# Apply a function of two inputs to every element in a list - Haskell

Tags: list, function, haskell

I have a function

```
f :: Int -> Int -> Int
```

and I have a list of arbitrary length but for the sake of the example:

```
[x1,x2,x3]
```

I need to apply f to the list such that the resulting list looks like this:

```
[f x1 x1 + f x1 x2 + f x1 x3 , f x2 x1 + f x2 x2 + f x2 x3 , f x3 x1 + f x3 x2 + f x3 x3]
```

I know that

```
map f [x1,x2,x3] will give [f x1, f x2, f x3]
```

but this doesn't seem like much help here.
What's the best way to do it?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [folds](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Fold)?

Comment: `appSum = (sum.) . join . liftM2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension, to illustrate try the following expression under ghci,

```
fun f xs = map sum [[ f x y | y <- xs] |  x <- xs]
```

Comment: please keep in mind that I do not know the length of the list.
3 is just the example

Comment: should be ok, it was to illustrate

Comment: Mixing `map`/`filter` with list comprehensions makes them both seem more complicated imo. `fun f xs = [sum [f x y | y <- xs] | x <-xs]` seems clearer.

Comment: map by definition map a function over a list and a list comprehension is just a list then It's not so complicated to associate them together. It start to be tricky when we have nested lc into lc. Here we have two level of imbrication starting at three I agree to say that using list comprehension is not a good choice and a fix is needed. Even if I don't find list comprehension really syntactically elegant and a solution as you provided imo is more elegant but hardest to catch at a first glance

Answer (score 4):

A solution without list comprehensions:

Use `map` twice.

```
map (\x -> sum $ map (f x) xs) xs
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use applicative functors to do it this way :

```
import Control.Applicative
let l = ["a", "b", "c"]
(++) <$> l <*> l
```

That will return `["aa","ab","ac","ba","bb","bc","ca","cb","cc"]`.

To explain a little bit further, `(++) <$> l` will map the function `(++)` on every element of `l`, thus returning `[("a"++), ("b"++), ("c"++)]`. Then, using `<*>` will apply all of these functions to all of the elements of `l`.

See the documentation about applicative functors for more details. http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Applicative.html